# I setup on local but when I run code I giving 404 error

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, project, laravel-code-generator

[image]

I attached image that what is showing. When I logged in after that it redirect to home page but here 404 error is showing. And I am new in Laravel and I don't have any idea what I should do and see lots of video regarding this and sped lot of time but 0 result.

Comment: Hey Sabia. Please update your post with a longed description of your problem, if you got it working before and if so - did you change anything to make it break? I'm sure you have more code than the Route-file, why did you only include that? Please add some details, so we can help properly. Thank you.

Comment: I updated please help me. I am new and I don't have any idea about this. what should i do to remove error 404

Answer (score 0):

@sabia Can you also share your, probably, HomeController. Or it looks like it is already wanting to go to some sort of shopping cart? So not after login anymore?

Or... if it does happen after login, your Auth\LoginController probably

Comment: class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        return view('frontend.user_login');
    }

    public function registration(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        if($request->has('referral_code')){
            Cookie::queue('referral_code', $request->referral_code, 43200);
        }
        return view('frontend.user_registration');
    }

Comment: this is code HomeController please check what can i do